# How to deploy a LOT of solutions between SharePoint 2007 and 2010 Farms

Tags: 2007, migration, solution-package

Right now we're moving from a SharePoint 2007 and SharePoint 2010 farm, my current list of solutions implemented in the 2007 farm numbers somewhere in the 100's.  A few ideas I had for moving them included:

1) PowerShell scripting the entire thing, building a script to loop over every .wsp, .cab, etc. and deploy.

2) Any third party utils or pre-built scripts that can help in this?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can script installs, but I wouldn't recommend doing a wholesale install of 100+ solutions.  I would evaluate them to see which ones are still needed and perform testing on them to see if they will cause any problems.  I understand that it will take a lot more work, but with that many solutions it would be pretty difficult to troubleshoot the system after the fact if there are any problems.

Comment: This would be done on an expendable dev platform first for testing, mostly these solutions are custom in-house stuff as opposed to third party, so being of a slightly lower quality I'm definitely expecting issues.

Answer (score 0):

see at http://kaldeera.codeplex.com/